# Go to a specific location when opening the document

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010, hyperlink, ms-word

I have a link to a word document in my sharepoint page and clicking on this will open the whole document. But when opening the document I want to go to a specific location in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a different location window using jQuery:

```
$('.class').click(function(e) 
{
   window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this   use the label   for refrence the id="flag"

```
<script>
<a href="#flag">go to flag</a>
</script>
<html>
<h3 id="flag" >flag</h3>
</html>
```